# PHP function to validate array elements for n level

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have tried out with the google and tried myself to get done for the below functionality. I need a function that will validate each array element whether it is scalar or not. So i wrote a simple function that will iterate each element of the array and checks for scalar or not.

But the real requirement, the array could be a multi dimentional array. So i have modified the array and called the function recursively as below, But it will not go-through all elements in the array.

```
function validate_scalar($params)
{
    foreach ($params as $key => $arg)
    {
        if (is_array($arg))
        {
            validate_scalar($arg);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!is_scalar($arg))
            {
                  // throwing an exception here if not scalar.
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there any method to achieve this functionality? Please help me on this.

Comment: Either there is a static missing in the function declaration, or the self in self::validate_scalar is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I have just modified the sample code.

Comment: array_walk_recursive
Goes through every item recursively that is not an array and executes the callback/function on them.

Comment: hmm could you explain what you mean by "not going through all the elements of the array"? I tested the code as is and it catches everything PHP does not consider to be a scalar (array, resource, object). http://codepad.org/g9QR2eqJ

Comment: What's the question? Your original code works when I add a `throw` where the comment is.

Comment: Also, you don't need `return true` if you're not using the result.

Comment: I assume that's the base case for recursion.

Comment: @UselessIntern The base case is the `else` clause. He's not using the value -- it returns when successful, it throws an error when it fails.

Comment: One problem with this function: you can't call it on a scalar -- you can't write `validate_scalar(3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

You could use something like this:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'kalle' => 'asdf', 
    'anka' => array(
        123, 
        54324, 
        new stdClass()
    )
);

array_walk_recursive($array, function ($item, $key) {
    if (!is_scalar($item)) {
        echo $key . " =>  : Is not scalar\n";
        return false;
    }
    echo $key . " =>  : Is scalar\n";
    return true;
});
```

array_walk_recursive ignores values that are arrays

output:

```
kalle =>  : Is scalar
0 =>  : Is scalar
1 =>  : Is scalar
2 =>  : Is not scalar
```